# Code work when wifi off and 3G on but not when wifioff and 4G

Tags: android, android-wifi, network-protocols

what i have done is

i am playing stream in wifi and 3g is also on.
I disabled the wifi, stream stops but restart immidately cause 3g is enable.

But problem starts when wifi and 4g is on, that time its not working

i added listener like

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
registerReceiver(receiver,intentFilter) ;
```

And receiver is

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



            try{  {
                if(GetNetworkStatus.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext()))
                   {if(!mIsPlaying)
                    justPlay();

                   }
                else
                {justStop();

                 handler=new Handler();

                    r = new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {

                            try{
                                Thread.sleep(4000);
                                }
                                catch(Exception s)
                                {}
                            if(GetNetworkStatus.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext()))
                            justPlay();
                            /*if(!mIsPlaying)
                            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);*/
                        }
                    };
                    try{
                         handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

                     }
                     catch(Exception e)
                     {

                     }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                finish();
            } }
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe logging the ***Extra*** content information, might help you determining the actual cause. 
Ref url: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

> A change in network connectivity has occurred. A default connection
>   has either been established or lost. The NetworkInfo for the affected
>   network is sent as an extra; it should be consulted to see what kind
>   of connectivity event occurred.
>
> If this is a connection that was the result of failing over from a
>   disconnected network, then the FAILOVER_CONNECTION boolean extra is
>   set to true.
>
> For a loss of connectivity, if the connectivity manager is attempting
>   to connect (or has already connected) to another network, the
>   NetworkInfo for the new network is also passed as an extra. This lets
>   any receivers of the broadcast know that they should not necessarily
>   tell the user that no data traffic will be possible. Instead, the
>   receiver should expect another broadcast soon, indicating either that
>   the failover attempt succeeded (and so there is still overall data
>   connectivity), or that the failover attempt failed, meaning that all
>   connectivity has been lost.
>
> For a disconnect event, the boolean extra EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY is set
>   to true if there are no connected networks at all.
>
> Constant Value: "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"

And in your GetNetworkStatus.isNetworkAvailable(), did you check for LTE connection type properly?
You could use following method (collected from elsewhere but works pretty good)

```
public static String getNetworkClass(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(info==null || !info.isConnected())
        return "-"; //not connected
    if(info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
        return "WIFI";
    if(info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
        int networkType = info.getSubtype();
        switch (networkType) {
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
                return "2G";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
                return "3G";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
                return "4G";
            default:
                return "?";
         }
    }
    return "?";
}
```

Comment: GetNetworkStatus.isNetworkAvailable()
code
  public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    con=context;
     ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
               = (ConnectivityManager)con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
         return activeNetworkInfo != null;
     }